# Cross Origin Issue AngularJS's Directives in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, eclipse

Hello I have problem when use Angular JS in Eclipse.
I try to use Directives.
But when i access the index.html file i get the Cors Origin Issue when load Directives template.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/fanjavaid/Documents/Research%20and%20Development/workspaces_angularjs/usedirectives/app/js/directives/ArticleInfo.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Here is my directive's javascript :

```
app.directive('articleInfo', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info : '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/ArticleInfo.html'
    }
});
```

And this is my Directive's template :

```
<div class="title"><h1>{{ article.title }}</h1></div>
<div class="meta" style="font-size:11px;"><strong>{{ article.meta }}</strong>, <strong>Comments :</strong> {{ article.comments }}</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>{{ article.content }}</p>
</div>
```

How to handle that?
Thank you

Comment: Just serve it from any (local) webserver instead of browsing to your index.html via file://

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are directly opening the static file `index.html` in your browser and on load, your directive is making a call to get the template using `templateUrl` and it always appends the path to current path in your browser which is `file://`. That is the reason your request is failing.

If you're using Java, You can deploy your application on any server like Jetty or TomCat and access your `index.html` and it will work.